# Extract matching year for week number in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

In postgresql `extract(week from '2014-12-30'::timestamp)` gives week number 1 of 2015.  How do I extract the associated year that corresponds to the week number?  Using `extract(year ...` gives 2014

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since `week` is the ISO-defined week, you want the `isoyear`:

```
#= select extract(isoyear from '2014-12-30'::timestamp);
 date_part
-----------
      2015
(1 row)
```

From the [docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT):

> By definition, ISO weeks start on Mondays and the first week of a year
>   contains January 4 of that year. In other words, the first Thursday of
>   a year is in week 1 of that year.
>
> In the ISO week-numbering system, it is possible for early-January
>   dates to be part of the 52nd or 53rd week of the previous year, and
>   for late-December dates to be part of the first week of the next year.
>   For example, 2005-01-01 is part of the 53rd week of year 2004, and
>   2006-01-01 is part of the 52nd week of year 2005, while 2012-12-31 is
>   part of the first week of 2013. It's recommended to use the isoyear
>   field together with week to get consistent results.

Comment: Ungh, googling "postgresql week" sent me to 8.1, not 9.4... so I didn't see it... freaking google.  Thanks!

Comment: Heh, I feel your pain. Only recently got into the habit of clicking the latest version after I land.

Answer (score -1):

According to the [postgresql documentation for extract week](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT):

> The number of the week of the year that the day is in. By definition
>   (ISO 8601), the first week of a year contains January 4 of that year.
>   (The ISO-8601  week starts on Monday.) In other words, the first
>   Thursday of a year is  in week 1 of that year. (for timestamp values
>   only)

Based on this, you might have to do a little logic:

```
case when extract(week from '2014-12-30'::timestamp) = 1 
     and extract(month from '2014-12-30'::timestamp) = 12
  then extract(year from '2014-12-30'::timestamp)+1
  else extract(year from '2014-12-30'::timestamp)
end
```